# How to remove back button from navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have that code. It can add edit button to navigatin bar, but back button still exists, but it becomes unresponsible.

```
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Edit"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:nil 
                               action:nil];
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setRightBarButtonItem:editButton];

[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.items objectAtIndex:1]setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

simply and short:

```
  self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
```

or

```
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: can NSLog the self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem

Comment: id but = [[self.navigationController.navigationBar.items objectAtIndex:1]backBarButtonItem] returns null pointer... :(

Comment: i think you do something wrong with your navigation- Bar/Controller

Comment: Back button does not go away unless this is done prior pushing viewController on the stack. @Prince answer works every time.

Answer (score 7):

I have done something similar to this before. In the controller that's going to push the next view controller that you don't want a back button in put this wherever you're doing your pushViewController:

```
 myNextViewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:myNextViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Yes. Doing it before the viewController is pushed is the right way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use

Objective-C:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Swift:

```
navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Either of these will work

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old but after reading this today the answer of:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

is correct but is incomplete, this needs to be done at a later life cycle method then viewDidLoad, aka toss it in viewWillApper or something later and it will work

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}
```

Hope this helps someone looking at an old post as I did today